# Why is the user logged out after visiting a specific page? (Drupal 7)

Tags: session, drupal-7

My problem occurs after a user of my website has logged in and tries to edit the account info. As soon as they visit the /user/{user-id}/edit page it is like the login-session is killed. They can navigate around the rest of the site just fine.

Any ideas of what could cause this or how to find out how I can keep the session alive? Maybe there is a way to force the user to stay logged in?

Comment: Did you set `$cookie_domain = '.xxxxxxxxx.com';` in your _setting.php_, if yes then you have to change it for current url.

Comment: The $cookie_domain variable is commented out. I tried to change it to my current domain but it didn't solve the issue. Thanks for the suggestion - it was one of the things that I haven't tried yet :)

Comment: Did you clear the cache

Comment: I've never run into anything like this. This could easily be done in a custom module though. Maybe check those? Or maybe there's something enabled that logs the user out when they visit a page they don't have access to?

Comment: Cache is cleared. I will try and run through the custom modules and come back if i have any luck :)

Comment: Update: I went through the custom modules and found a block of code that destroyed the sessions... Don't know why but removing it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that your cookie is set for both http and https sessions.  Sometimes, if you appeared to be logged out, it may be because the user went from a secure https connection to an http connection.

Comment: Confirmed. The user goes from one secure connection to another. I am trying to run through all of the custom modules now to see if any of these could be causing the issue :)

Comment: Confirmed. The user goes from one secure connection to another. I am trying to run through all of the custom modules now to see if any of these could be causing the issue :)

Comment: Update: I went through the custom modules and found a block of code that destroyed the sessions... Don't know why but removing it helped :) Thanks for the tip!